# How to ignore corrupted files in AWS Glue DataBrew?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue-databrew

I have many JSONs. I initially want to use AWS Glue to process directly. However, due to it is [too dirty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77356900/json-array-field-changes-to-double-int-string-struct-format-in-aws-glue), I turned to use AWS Glue DataBrew for some cleaning work first.

I have succeed using one recipe to clean hundreds of million files until I got error for one folder:

```bash
ERROR - Failed to load dataset from 's3://my-bucket/millions-of-jsons-group-18/'. Exception An error occurred while calling o326.json.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 109 in stage 21.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 109.3 in stage 21.0 (TID 11620, 172.34.206.101, executor 6): java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of input stream
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.decompress(DecompressorStream.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:105)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.loadMore(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:180)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._parseNumber2(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1455)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._parsePosNumber(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1363)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:839)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:737)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JacksonUtils$.nextUntil(JacksonUtils.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$.inferField(JsonInferSchema.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$.inferField(JsonInferSchema.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$.inferField(JsonInferSchema.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(JsonInferSchema.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(JsonInferSchema.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2543)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(JsonInferSchema.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(JsonInferSchema.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.reduceLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:185)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceLeft(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.reduceLeftOption(TraversableOnce.scala:203)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceLeftOption(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.reduceOption(TraversableOnce.scala:210)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceOption(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$$anonfun$1.apply(JsonInferSchema.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$$anonfun$1.apply(JsonInferSchema.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$.infer(JsonInferSchema.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.MultiLineJsonDataSource$$anonfun$infer$1.apply(JsonDataSource.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.MultiLineJsonDataSource$$anonfun$infer$1.apply(JsonDataSource.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.MultiLineJsonDataSource$.infer(JsonDataSource.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonDataSource.inferSchema(JsonDataSource.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat.inferSchema(JsonFileFormat.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$6.apply(DataSource.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$6.apply(DataSource.scala:180)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:391)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of input stream
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.decompress(DecompressorStream.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:105)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.loadMore(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:180)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._parseNumber2(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1455)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._parsePosNumber(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1363)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:839)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:737)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JacksonUtils$.nextUntil(JacksonUtils.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$.inferField(JsonInferSchema.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$.inferField(JsonInferSchema.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$.inferField(JsonInferSchema.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(JsonInferSchema.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(JsonInferSchema.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2543)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(JsonInferSchema.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(JsonInferSchema.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.reduceLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:185)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceLeft(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.reduceLeftOption(TraversableOnce.scala:203)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceLeftOption(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.reduceOption(TraversableOnce.scala:210)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceOption(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$$anonfun$1.apply(JsonInferSchema.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$$anonfun$1.apply(JsonInferSchema.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Based on the error "JsonInferSchema" inside, I am guessing is one file in this folder is "corrupted". (Please correct me if I am wrong)

Is there a way to set env in AWS Glue DataBrew like [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63903300/2000548)?

> spark.sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles", "true")

Also, if can set, is there a way to list the corrupted files being ignored? Thanks!